# ViewPagerIndicator click to change ViewPager item

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Is it possible to implement a functionality that when you click on a indicator, the view page go to requested page through `ViewPagerIndicator` and `ViewPager`?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: ViewPagerIndicator is a library, containing many indicators. AFAIK, none of those indicators are named "ViewPagerIndicator". Some offer interactivity (e.g., `TabPagerIndicator`), others may not.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah your right, I'm currently using line indicator through mentioned library, is it possible to accomplish this functionality over this library?

Comment: I have not use that particular indicator, but if it is what I think it is, it is non-interactive. However, it is open source, so you can tweak the source to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your true means you can do this with overriding

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```

hope to be usefull

Comment: Where should I override this? Unfortunately, there is no function with this name in `JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator`!

Comment: you should use your Adapter that extend from FragmentPagerAdapter you can find more code on sample directory of this library